# Clonezilla mounts external HDD

Tags: 16.04, mount, clonezilla

When running Clonezilla the program mounts the external HDD when "Informing the OS of partition table changes...". Why does it do that? It started doing that out of the blue. Commenting out the entry in /etc/fstab does nothing. Clonezilla is installed into Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you install clonezilla into Ubuntu, or are you running Clonezilla from a drive made from a Clonezilla iso file?

Comment: Clonezilla is installed into Ubuntu

Comment: I have been using the *stable versions of the Clonezilla iso files* (which are based on Debian). Maybe you can download such a version and check if the same thing happens also in that case. I would think that the stable versions are the main ones, and that things are most likely to work well there. -- I would guess that mounting happens because the command to inform the OS makes Ubuntu think the external drive was just plugged in, and there is a setting in your Ubuntu system to automount external drives (maybe only USB drives), when plugged in.

Comment: You are right. Running partprobe mounts the disk. When unmounting I am prompted for the password. I disabled automount in dconf editor (org.gnome.desktop.media-handling). I thought all mounting is done in /etc/fstab. Where is this setting located? autofs?

Answer (score 1):

I think the settings for automounting can found and modified in different locations (GUI tools) between standard Ubuntu and each of the community flavours.

In standard Ubuntu 16.04.x LTS you can try via

- *System Settings* (the button with the cog wheel and the crankshaft)

  - <kbd>Details</kbd>

    - *Removable Media* (menu item)

      - <kbd>Other Media ...</kbd>

        - Try some of the *Type* options, 'maybe HD DVD video disc'
        - Select the *Action* 'Do nothing'

[image]

Comment: Nothing.  I did solve the problem by deleting tons of files, including some configuration data from my home folder. Thanks through